# export csv: enclose key with quotes in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, double-quotes, sqlyog

I am exporting a mysql table to csv using SQLYog.

I can get all the fields enclosed with `" "`, except for the id column which is first, primary key and set to int.

I've tried removing the primary key and changing the id column to text, but to no avail.

Not sure if this is because it is the first column, id, primary key or what.

Comment: Also when exporting open the csv in a text editor. I was opening the file in excel and excel was formating the id as numeric and removing the double quotes around all the cells in that column!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following settings from SQLyog (12.1.2):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try another editor for example *notepad* to open your csv file. the quotes " " should be there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).